# Testing an Apache Camel route with vm and file component over ftp

Tags: unit-testing, apache-camel, camel-ftp

I have two very simple routes (Code below is not the original classes, I have simplified it like removing setters, logs and so on)

The first route:

```
public static final String MESSAGE_CONSUMER = "vm:myMessage";

public String myXmlProducer; //and getter method then

myXmlProducer = "file:myFileLocation?autoCreate=true&fileName="+ myFileName;
from(MESSAGE_CONSUMER)
    //some process here
    .to(myXmlProducer);
```

and the second one:

```
public String fileConsumer = "file:myFileLocation";
public String ftpProducer = "ftp://ftpIp?username=username&password=password&maximumReconnectAttempts=0";

from(fileConsumer)
    .to(ftpProducer );
```

I am trying to write some test for these two routes, here is some part of my test class,

configuration part in class:

```
public static final String MOCK_OUT = "mock:out";
public static final String DIRECT_IN = "direct:in";
public static final String MOCK_XML_URI = "mock:xmlFile";
...
@EndpointInject(uri = MOCK_OUT)
MockEndpoint mockOut;

@EndpointInject(uri = MOCK_XML_URI)
MockEndpoint mockXmlUri;
...

@Override
public RouteBuilder[] createRouteBuilders() {
    final MyRoute route = new MyRoute();
    route.setFtpProducer (MOCK_OUT);

    RouteBuilder testHarness = new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from(DIRECT_IN).routeId("testHarness.in")
                .to(MyRoute.MESSAGE_CONSUMER)

            from(route.getMyXmlProducer())
                .convertBodyTo(Byte.class)
                .to(mockXmlUri)
        }
    };
    return new RouteBuilder[] {route, testHarness};
}

@Before
public void getTestData() throws IOException {
    testInputData = IOUtils.toString(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myTarget/inputData.txt"));
}
```

This test method is green:

```
@Test
public void testRoutingOk() throws InterruptedException {
    mockOut.setExpectedMessageCount(1);
    mockOut.message(0).body().isEqualTo(testInputData);

    template.sendBody("file:myTestFileLocation", testInputData);
    assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
}
```

The problem is the following test, I am quiet new in camel, and have googled to find why, but cannot figure it out by myself:

```
@Test
public void testRoutingOk() throws InterruptedException {
    mockXmlUri.setExpectedMessageCount(1);
    mockXmlUri.message(0).body().isEqualTo(testInputData);

    template.sendBody(DIRECT_IN, testInputData);
    assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
}
```

I get assetion error, no message at all:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: mock://xmlFile Received message count. Expected: <1> but was: <0>
```

Is there anyone who can help me, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days struggling, I found what the problem was. I am sending a message to body but, this message will be used by another route. I am using version 2.10, the solution to have a green unit test is to stop the route. With current version (2.10) it will be a little bit complicated, since I should change my main classes just for unit tests sake. But I can use controlbus: instead, if we upgrade our camel to 2.11+.